# add a newline character after </tr> shell

Tags: bash, shell, sed, web-scraping, newline

I am learning the basics of writing a website scraper. After downloading the website, I want to extract the information between `<tr>` and `</tr>`.

```
$ cat < file
<tr><td>Adopt</td><td>H<u>a</u>nai</td></tr><tr><td>Affection</td><td>Pumehana</td></tr>
```

My goal is to get something like this

```
$cat < clean
Adopt Hanai
Affection Pumehana
```

I want to first use `sed` to add a newline char after the pattern `<tr>.*<\tr>`, then delete the everything with pattern <.*> but not sure how to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: sed is not the right tool for the job. Take a look at a proper HTML parser. There are many options in python or perl.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I know there are better tools, but my teacher says to use sed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
sed $'s/<\/tr><tr>/&\\\n/g; s/<\/td><td>/ /g; s/<[^>]*>//g' file
Adopt Hanai
Affection Pumehana
```

However it is better to use a dedicated HTML parser for more complex HTML parsing.